# getting sum using sql with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access

I m having data in columns as: -

```
  Process   Volume      TAT
  1            1        Pass
  1            2        Fail
  2            5        Fail
  2            5        Pass
  3            1        Pass
  4            6        Fail
  4            4        Pass
```

Now grouping by Process, i want the sum of volume (not taking into account whatever TAT), sum of volume where TAT  = Pass, sum of Volume where TAT = Fail.

Like this

```
Process     Total Volume    Volume(TAT=Pass)    Volume(TAT = Fail)
1           3               1                   2
2           10              5                   5
...
...
```

Comment: That's nice - what have you tried?  And for what database?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For SQL Server, you can use `CASE` expressions to conditionally determine the amount you need to add, then `SUM` them together, like this:

```
SELECT Process, SUM(Volume) AS TotalVolume, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN TAT = 'Pass' THEN Volume ELSE 0 END) AS Pass,
    SUM(CASE WHEN TAT = 'Fail' THEN Volume ELSE 0 END) AS Fail
FROM (
     -- Dummy data here for testing
    SELECT 1 AS Process, 1 as Volume, 'Pass' AS TAT
    UNION SELECT 1, 2, 'Fail'
    UNION SELECT 2, 5, 'Fail'
    UNION SELECT 2, 5, 'Pass'
    UNION SELECT 3, 1, 'Pass'
    UNION SELECT 4, 6, 'Fail'
    UNION SELECT 4, 4, 'Pass'
) MyTable
GROUP BY Process
ORDER BY Process
```

For Microsoft Access, `CASE` isn't supported, so you can use `SWITCH` or `IIF`, like so:

```
SUM(IIF(TAT = 'Pass', Volume, 0)) AS Pass
```

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya - sure, just change `SUM(CASE WHEN TAT = 'Pass' THEN Volume ELSE 0 END)` to `SUM(IIF(TAT = 'Pass', Volume, 0)) AS Pass`.  You should edit your question with any apppropriate tags so people don't waste time working on answers that won't work.

Comment: i have used sum(switch(w.[TAT]='Pass',w.[Volume], w.[TAT] = 'Fail',0)) as VolumePass.... i think switch and iif would not differ?