# Counting by dates in a loop in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been working with about 20k records, I don't need all the information, I just need aggregate totals as snapshots of certain times in the records history. Luckily each of the events has a column that records the date of the event, some of those dates will be null in the instance that a particular event never happened to that record. But a couple of the stages, can only be calculated by other fields, for instance a stage of "In Progress" can only be determined by the existence of a create date and either a null in the submit date or a submit date greater than the create date for example in pseudo:

```
if createDate <= @runDate && (submitDate=null || submitDate > @runDate)
In_Progress_count = In_Progress_count + 1
```

Any of the other fields are simply counted if the date in the field is less than or equal to the field so for example:

```
if approvedDate <= @runDate
Approved_count = Approved_count+1
```

For example I have data that looks something like this:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Application | Applicant    | Program      | Create Date  | Accept       |Active Duplicate| Cond. Accept     | Defer            | Deposited        | Divert           | Duplicate        | Early Quit       | Incomplete       | Ineligible       | Pending          | Review           | Purge            | Reject           | Withdraw         |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 1           | Peg Bundy    | Comp-Sci     | 2013-08-01   | <null>       | <null>         | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           |
| 2           | Marcy Darcy  | Comp-Sci     | 2013-08-25   | 2013-09-05   | <null>         | <null>           | <null>           | 2013-09-30       | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | 2013-08-30       | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | 2013-10-01       | <null>           |
| 3           | Al Bundy     | Language     | 2013-09-01   | 2013-09-05   | <null>         | <null>           | <null>           | 2013-09-27       | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | 2013-09-05       | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | <null>           | 2013-09-27       |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I'm trying to get a result for a query that looks like this if run with '2013-09-26' as the @rundate:

```
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| Program Name  | totalApps    | countAccept  |ActivDuplicates | countCondAccept  | countDefer       | countDeposited   | countDivert      | countDuplicate   | countEarlyQuit   | countIncomplete  | countIneligible  | countPending     | countReview      | countPurge       | countReject      | countWithdraw    |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  Comp-Sci     | 2            | 1            | 0              | 0                | <null>           | 1                | 0                | 0                | 0                | 1                | 0                | 0                | 0                | 0                | 0                | 0                |
|  Language     | 1            | 1            | 0              | 0                | <null>           | 0                | 0                | 0                | 0                | 1                | 0                | 0                | 0                | 0                | 0                | 0                |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

What I've tried so far is to count by date on each of the colums, but I'm getting the wrong totals because I only know how to look at one column to asses the date, so basically it's counting everything that's not null even dates past the date I'm trying

```
SELECT Programs_Name, 
Reported_Application_Stage, 
count(Reported_Application_Stage) AS AppStageTotal, 
count(SubmitDate) AS AppSubmitted, 
count(Application_Accept_Date) AS AcceptDate, 
count(Deposit_Paid_Date) AS Deposited, 
count(Defer_Date) AS Deferred, 
count(Deny_Date) AS Denied, 
count(Divert_Date) AS Divert, 
count(Early_Quit) AS EarlyQuit, 
count(Ineligible_Date) AS Ineligible, 
count(Purge_Date) AS Purged, 
FROM  ExtractApplications
WHERE (Report_Date1='2013-09-27')
GROUP BY ExtractSnapshots.Report_Date1, ExtractSnapshots.id, .Programs, .Reported_Application_Stage, _Program, _Start_Term_Year, _Start_Term, _Decision_Display_Value;
```

Although I can really easily get any specific stages values by date easily using this and they're correct:

```
SELECT Programs_Name,  
count(Defer_Date) AS Deferred
FROM ExtractApplication
WHERE Defer_Date <='2013-09-26'
GROUP BY Programs_Name;
```

The problem being that I have about 100 dates that I have to use, and about 15 stages that I'm looking for, and I can't really sit and run 1500 queries one at a time for the next week or so without getting fired :P

So what I'm trying to do, is find the right query to count each field, I honestly just don't know how to use the count() function with the types of parameters I'm trying to use I've tried `count(someField<'2013-09-27')` and it didn't work, I also don't know how to find the "In Progress" field that relies on a `createDate` combined with a `null or >` date value in the `submitDate` field

To top all of that off, I need to put it into a loop that will run this with the dates being the first, eigth, fifteenth, and twenty second of each month over the last few years, and running a loop in SQL is something I don't know how to do, if it were java I would just nest two for loops that run off of array sizes like:

```
for (i=0; i<year.length;i++) {
    for (j=1; j<13; j++) {
         for (k=0; k<setDays.length) {
               runDate=year[i]+'-'+j+'-'+setDays[k];
         }
     }
}
```

(I only include that because that's how I think of this happening contextually as I'm a PHP/Java programmer mainly and not a database admin)

I could really use some help here as I'm at a loss of what to do and I've spent a ton of time working on this already.

Comment: Try `SUM(CASE WHEN Reported_Application_Stage Is Null Then 0 Else 1 END)`

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or Jet / ACE? If your database is SQL Server, then @DaveJohnson's comment may suit, if you are using Jet / ACE then it is a different story.

Comment: I'm using Access, I didn't even notice the sql-server tag I put in there.  I've basically exported a table from our CRM into excel and created a table out of it using Access and then we're going to re-import it into a new object we're creating.  I'm really really sorry for that mistake :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is SQL Server, and not Access...

This should get you going in the right direction.  This is effectively what @DaveJohnson suggested, with a twist in that it only counts each column if the date is before/on the @RunDate (and not null).

```
DECLARE @RunDate DATE
SET @RunDate = '2013-12-01'

DECLARE @DATA TABLE (AppID INT,Applicant VARCHAR(100),Program VARCHAR(100),CreateDate DATE,Accept DATE,ActiveDuplicate DATE,CondAccept DATE,Defer DATE,Depostited DATE,Divert DATE,Duplicate DATE,EarlyQuit DATE,Incomplete DATE,Ineligible DATE,Pending DATE,Review DATE,Purge DATE,Reject DATE,Withdraw DATE)
INSERT INTO @DATA
SELECT 1,'Peg Bundy','Comp-Sci','2013-08-01',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,'Marcy Darcy','Comp-Sci','2013-08-25','2013-09-05',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2013-09-30',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2013-08-30',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2013-10-01',NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Al Bundy','Language','2013-09-01','2013-09-05',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2013-09-27',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2013-09-05',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2013-09-27'

SELECT Program
     , SUM(CASE WHEN CreateDate IS NULL OR CreateDate>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS CreateDate
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Accept IS NULL OR Accept>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Accept
     , SUM(CASE WHEN ActiveDuplicate IS NULL OR ActiveDuplicate>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS ActiveDuplicate
     , SUM(CASE WHEN CondAccept IS NULL OR CondAccept>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS CondAccept
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Defer IS NULL OR Defer>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Defer
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Depostited IS NULL OR Depostited>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Depostited
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Divert IS NULL OR Divert>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Divert
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Duplicate IS NULL OR Duplicate>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Duplicate
     , SUM(CASE WHEN EarlyQuit IS NULL OR EarlyQuit>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS EarlyQuit
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Incomplete IS NULL OR Incomplete>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Incomplete
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Ineligible IS NULL OR Ineligible>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Ineligible
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Pending IS NULL OR Pending>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Pending
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Review IS NULL OR Review>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Review
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Purge IS NULL OR Purge>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Purge
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Reject IS NULL OR Reject>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Reject
     , SUM(CASE WHEN Withdraw IS NULL OR Withdraw>@RunDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS Withdraw
FROM @DATA
GROUP BY Program
```

Comment: I'm so sorry about the sql-server tag, I need an Access solution. If worse comes to worse I guess I could create a local sql-server and then use the sum(case when) solution.

Comment: No worries, only took a couple minutes to type out. I can't help with Access, I'm not familiar enough with it.  I'll leave answer for Googlers.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a conditional CASE WHEN construct within your aggregation.  Also, avoid looping in SQL for your dates as SQL Server is not optimized for this.  You can build a date range and then join to that for an efficient set-based solution.

This is a SQL Server (2005+) only answer.

ex:

```
WITH [cte] AS
(

    SELECT 
        [date]
    FROM ( -- build date range
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE())) -- avoid overflow
            DATEADD(DAY,-1 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [Date]
        FROM sys.all_objects O1
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects O2 -- if you need LOTS of days
    ) A
    WHERE [date] BETWEEN '01 Jan 2010' AND GETDATE() -- set these accordingly
        AND DAY([date]) IN (1,8,15,22)
)
SELECT
    [Programs_Name],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [SubmitDate] <= B.[date] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [AppSubmitted],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Application_Accept_Date] <= B.[date] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [AcceptDate],
    ...
FROM ExtractApplications A
CROSS JOIN [cte] B 
GROUP BY [Programs_Name]
```

Comment: again, I'm so so sorry about the sql-server tag, after all that entry into the post I must have added the sql-server tag by accident. I feel so bad. I need an Access solution, or a link to how to install a sql-server instance locally (I have server management studio already)

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry that I derped on the "sql-server" tags guys, and I appreciate the help, but I figured it out.

Instead of using `SUM(CASE WHEN field=x THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` I found that the equivalent of that in Access is basically `SUM(IIF(field=x, 1, 0))` thanks to LittleBobbyTables (fantastic username) over in this thread [getting sum using sql with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722852/getting-sum-using-sql-with-multiple-conditions)

So what I was looking for in the combined field is `SUM(IIF((createDate<=@myDate AND (submitDate>@myDate OR submitDate=null),1,0))` and the rest of the columns work via `SUM(IIF(column<=@myDate, 1, 0))`

Thanks again guys!