# Divide one by another in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I think I am over complicating this.

I'm not fantastic at SQL so I need to use the query builder at times.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I want my query to show me:

Managers name

Number of times the managers name is in the table

The number of disputes that equal TRUE

disputes divided by total times manager is in the table

**Current SQL**

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_Quality_Disputes.LoggedDate, tbl_Quality_Disputes.Manager, Count(tbl_Quality_Disputes.Manager) AS CountOfManager, [Decision]/[Manager] AS Success_Rate
    FROM tbl_Quality_Disputes
    GROUP BY tbl_Quality_Disputes.LoggedDate, tbl_Quality_Disputes.Manager, tbl_Quality_Disputes.Decision, [Decision]/[Manager]
    HAVING (((tbl_Quality_Disputes.Decision)="Approved"));
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can provide the schema then it would be easy to help.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT when GROUP BY - how come?

Comment: The HAVING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: I thought I would use DISTINCT because the managers names are in there more than once - I can see why its not needed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the grouping you need. In your result you want a row for each manager, so that's it, definitely no `Decision`.

Then, you're right in not placing the filtering on the decision in the `WHERE` clause, because that would remove the rows from the count(*) as well, but `HAVING` is meant for conditions on aggregated fields, so you cannot put it there either. Since you need that filtering on one of the aggregations but not on the other, you can use a `case` inside the aggregation where it's needed.

Finally, the calculation of the success rate should be based on the counts, not on the `Manager` and `Decision` fields.

I ignored the `LoggedDate` field as its meaning is not clear, but if you explain it a bit I will edit my query so that it can fit in

```
SELECT  Manager,
        COUNT(*) AS CountOfManager,
        SUM(case when Decision = "Approved" then 1 else 0 end) AS Decision,
        SUM(case when Decision = "Approved" then 1 else 0 end) / Count(*) AS Success_Rate
FROM    tbl_Quality_Disputes
GROUP BY  Manager
```

As a side note, I removed the table name from all fields prefixes because when using a single table it's not needed and makes the query much more verbose. When using two or more tables it's good practice to prefix the column names, but you can give aliases to the tables to make everything a bit more compact.

**Edit**

Since the `LoggedDate` will be the same for all the rows of the same Manager, you can either add to the `GROUP BY` or aggregate it with a `MIN` or `MAX` (I prefer the latter option, I find it more robust).

Regarding the error you got, that's probably because [Access doesn't support the `CASE` expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722852/getting-sum-using-sql-with-multiple-conditions) (sorry, didn't know that). I replaced it with `IIF`, now it shold work.

```
SELECT  Manager,
        MAX(LoggedDate) AS MaxLoggedDate,
        COUNT(*) AS CountOfManager,
        SUM(IIF(Decision = "Approved", 1, 0)) AS CountOfDecision,
        SUM(IIF(Decision = "Approved", 1, 0)) / Count(*) AS Success_Rate
FROM    tbl_Quality_Disputes
GROUP BY  Manager
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply - Appreciate it. LoggedDate is the date the manager was added to the table. I have this in so that we can filter by date ranges.

I have used your SQL but receiving a syntax error (missing operator) in SUM(case when Decision = "Approved" then 1 else 0 end)

Comment: Thank you again for the help - Apologies for being a pain. Its throwing out another error: The SELECT statement includes a reserved work or arguments name that is misspelled or missing

Comment: I understand this is the line causing the error:         SUM(IIF(Decision = "Approved", 1, 0)) / Count(*) AS Success_Rate

Comment: My bad, I was missing a `,` after `AS Decision` and an alias for the new aggregated column... can you try again?

Comment: Thank you again for such a quick reply - I hope I am not stressing you out to much but there is another error: Circular reference caused by alias 'Decision' in query definitions SELECT list.

Comment: LOL, fixed again... I used the column names themselves as aliases, and seems that Access won't like that. Sorry, didn't know about all these limitations

Comment: Jackpot - Thank you very much. You really went out of your way to help me. Hope you have a good week

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144242/discussion-between-stefano-zanini-and-dmorgan20).

Answer (score 0):

Try using below query,

```
SELECT tbl_Quality_Disputes.LoggedDate, tbl_Quality_Disputes.Manager, 
Count(tbl_Quality_Disputes.Manager) AS CountOfManager, [Decision]/[Manager] AS Success_Rate
    FROM tbl_Quality_Disputes
WHERE tbl_Quality_Disputes.Decision="Approved"
    GROUP BY tbl_Quality_Disputes.LoggedDate, tbl_Quality_Disputes.Manager, 
tbl_Quality_Disputes.Decision, [Decision]/[Manager];
```

Kindly provide sample data and expected output

Comment: Data type mismatch in criteria expression - Unfortunately as im in the office we are unable to upload sample data as dropbox and other websites are restricted

Comment: Is Decision and Manager are numeric datatype?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Datatypes are: Text

Comment: Since divide will not work. Values populated in those columns are numeric or string?

Comment: The data saved in decision and manger are string - But im under the impression that the SQL doing counts basically makes them numeric?